# In Vim, how to copy content in file and use it in command?

Tags: vim

For example, I open a file which includes

> FATAL ERROR: Simulation failed. Please read /path/to/the/error/file.error

What I want to do is copy the path of the error file, which I've already done that by "v" into the visual mode and "y" to copy it, and open that file by splitting the window by ":sp /path/to/the/error/file.error".

My problem is: how to paste the copied path in command mode?

Answer (score 3):

Vim also has a feature to open the filename under the cursor directly.

If you want to open it in a new split, then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd> (or the equivalent
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

See [`:help CTRL-W_f`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_f) for more details.

The mapping to open the file under the cursor in the current window (not in a new split) is [`gf`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gf).

Answer (score 1):

In command mode, use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, which is paste register, then  <kbd>"</kbd>  to paste the last yanked thing from the unnamed register.

to see your current registers, execute the following command `:reg`